# TextSpeech and Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, text, speech

I have a button and a text view in a Fragment.

How can I use TextToSpeech in that Fragment?

Code:

```
public class FragmentTab extends Fragment{
    Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, Nullable ViewGroup container, Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_1, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

I delete other code for textspeech because not works this all I have now...

Comment: Please add at least a snipped code of your works.

Answer (score 1):

> Put a method in your activity that will handle the speaking such as:

```
public void speak(String text) {
    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
  }
}
```

> Then in your fragment when you have a String to speak, here's an
>   example implementation:

```
String textToSpeak = "Hello from my fragment";
MyActivity myActivity = (MyActivity) getActivity();
myActivity.speak(textToSpeak);
```

> With something like this you'll be able to keep the TTS in your
>   activity but still speak phrases from the fragment.

Here's something to look at in the new code you posted:

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
```

From the documentation the constructor takes a Context and a Listener:

```
TextToSpeech(Context context, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener listener)
```

> Try this instead:

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(getActivity(), this);
```

Furthermore, if you use "this" as the listener, you would have to implement it.

Hope it will help my friend !